# Difficulty understanding a step in the proof of multiset version of Cauchy-Davenport Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, additive-combinatorics

In a paper "G. Kós, L. Rónyai, Alon’s Nullstellensatz for multisets, *Combinatorica*, 32(5) (2012) 589-605", the authors prove a multiset version of the Cauchy-Davenport Theorem (please see Theorem 14 on page-10 of the paper on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2901)

In the proof of this theorem, I am not able to understand (in the last paragraph) the meaning of "$f(x, y)$ vanishes at least $r > k + l$ times at $(a, b)$" and also not able to understand how does this conclusion gives a contradiction.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sentence means that $(a,b)$ is a root of the $f$ with multiplicity at least $r$, with $r>(k+\ell)$. Therefore $f(a,b)=0$, $f'(a,b)=0$, $\cdots$, $f^{(r-1)}(a,b)=0$. Not sure about that conclusion, I haven't read the paper.

Comment: That mean the coefficents of all terms of degree less than $r$ in Taylor expansion of $f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$ are $0$, contradiction because we have nonzero coefficent term $(x-a)^k(x-b)^l$ with $l<r$

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Thanks! It is understood now.

Comment: @VeronicaPhan Thanks! It is understood now.